# Do SFDX commands count toward limits?

Tags: salesforcedx, data-loader, limits

I am looking into utilizing some SFDX commands to possibly use for some data integrations and/or one-time loads.  Do these commands count toward the same API call limits as API calls and Bulk API calls?
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_data.htm

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, SFDX commands do consume and count towards the limits of the resources they utilize on your target orgs, including API calls, Bulk API jobs, streaming and platform event consumption, and others.

You can check your limits consumption (which also counts as an API call!) by doing `sfdx force:limits:api:display`.